# How can I prevent my child components re-rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm creating a calendar date range picker in react js and I'm running into an issue where, whenever I click a day in the calendar, all of the days end up re-rendering.

Here is my main calendar component

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import CalendarDay from './CalendarDay';

export default function Calendar(props) {
  const days = [
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21,
    22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31,
  ];

  const [selectedDates, setSelectedDates] = useState({
    start: null,
    end: null,
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(selectedDates);
  }, [selectedDates]);

  const handleDateSelect = useCallback(
    (day) => {
      if (!selectedDates.start) {
        setSelectedDates((prev) => ({ ...prev, start: day }));
      } else if (!selectedDates.end) {
        setSelectedDates((prev) => ({ ...prev, end: day }));
      } else {
        setSelectedDates({ start: day, end: null });
      }
    },
    [selectedDates.start, selectedDates.end]
  );

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setSelectedDates({ start: null, end: null })}>
        clear dates
      </button>
      <div>start: {selectedDates.start}</div>
      <div>end: {selectedDates.end}</div>

      <div className="calendar">
        {days.map((day, idx) => {
          const key = `${props.year}-${props.month}-${idx + 1}`;
          const isSelectedOrInRange = () => {
            if (
              selectedDates.start === day ||
              selectedDates.end === day ||
              (day <= selectedDates.end && day >= selectedDates.start)
            ) {
              return true;
            }
            return false;
          };
          return (
            <CalendarDay
              key={key}
              day={day}
              isSelectedOrInRange={isSelectedOrInRange()}
              handleDateSelect={handleDateSelect}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

And here is my `CalendarDay` component (this is whats always re-rendering)

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';

function CalendarDay(props) {
  const { handleDateSelect, day, isSelectedOrInRange } = props;

  console.log(' - rendering: ', day);

  return (
    <div
      className={'day' + (isSelectedOrInRange ? ' selected' : '')}
      onClick={() => handleDateSelect(day)}
    >
      {day}
    </div>
  );
}

export default memo(CalendarDay);
```

styles.css (imported in index.js)

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.calendar {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.day {
  width: calc(400px / 7);
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.selected {
  color: white;
  background: red;
}
```

Is there a way to prevent any calendarDay box from re-rendering unless its clicked on or a date in between the selection?

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-5wdhja?file=src%2Fstyle.css) for you to play around with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `React.memo`, the `CalendarDay` only renders when its props change, but you're changing the `handleDateSelect` function anytime `selectedDates.start` or `selectedDate.end` changes.

One way to avoid this is to only use the `prev` value in the `handleDateSelect` function, avoiding the need to declare any dependencies for the callback:

```js
 const handleDateSelect = useCallback(
    (day) => {
      setSelectedDates((prev) => 
        !prev.start
          ? { ...prev, start: day }
          : !prev.end
          ? { ...prev, end: day }
          : { start: day, end: null }
    },
    []
  );
```